# Jenkins on Windows: cannot run PowerShell scripts due to Execution Policy

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am running **Jenkins on Windows Server 2019** and I'm facing problems asking it to run some **PowerShell** script due to a **bad Execution Policy**:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins3203707218318955273.ps1

File C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins3203707218318955273.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins3203707218318955273.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current
system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
```

I checked the **Execution Policy** as my Administrator user and they seems to be good:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -list

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

Jenkins is running with the Local System Account:

[image]

I'm setting them using both an **Active Directory GPO** and a **Local Group Policy**:

[image]

[image]

Could you help me to find out where I'm wrong, please?

Comment: Is Jenkins running under your personal administrator account? (If so, that's a major mistake.) If not, then apparently the account that Jenkins is running under does not have the proper execution policy set for it.

Comment: I edited the question: Jenkins is running with the Local System Account.

Comment: Is the script downloaded from elsewhere? Run `Unblock-File C:\path\to\script.ps1` then try again

Comment: No, all scripts are local.

Comment: Why do you assume that the (local) Administrator account and the Local System Account shared the same privileges, shared the same environment, or were somehow related?

Comment: Try adding -Scope Process to your launch arguments or running from a location that isn't temp as AppLocker or something similar may prevent scripts from running even if your execution policy is good.

Comment: @IInspectable, I am assuming that Jenkins is using the LocalMachine policy which seems to be RemoteSigned.

Comment: @LordPupazz, I tried to add `-Scope Process` with the very same result.

Comment: *"I checked the Execution Policy as my Administrator user and they seems to be good"* - Why? What's the relevance of the (local) Administrator's environment? You aren't running anything under that account.

Comment: @IInspectable, ok so how I can check which policies are used by the Local System Account which is used by Jenkins?

Comment: By running the command (like `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list`) under the user account you wish to investigate.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, of course. But I cannot run it as the Local System Account, because that is the local COMPUTER account I cannot login with.

Comment: Why don't you think you can? Just register a task with the Task Scheduler and have it persist the output in a location you can access.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, but the `MachinePolicy` and `LocalMachine` policies would be applied by all users, right?

Comment: I don't know how group policies are evaluated.

Comment: `MachinePolicy` and `LocalMachine` are PowerShell execution policies, not Group Policies.

Comment: They are applied using group policies, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231705/discussion-between-mat-and-iinspectable).